# Django - RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to move my Django project to a production server(virtual machine running ubuntu server 14.04 LTS X64) freshly installed.

All I did so far is installing the project requirements.txt (no apache server installed nor mysql server)

When I try to run `manage.py runserver` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

I have no idea how to trace the source of this issue, and if you need any information let me know.

requirements.txt:

```
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.22
celery==3.1.19
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.7.1
django-appconf==0.6
django-celery==3.1.17
django-compressor==1.4
django-discover-runner==1.0
django-role-permissions==0.6.2
djangorestframework==3.0.0
drf-nested-routers==0.11.1
gunicorn==19.1.1
kombu==3.0.33
mysql-connector-python==2.1.3
pytz==2015.7
six==1.8.0
static3==0.5.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying running `manage.py`alone, i got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 108, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/soufiaane/django_projects/CapValue/CapValue/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery_settings import app as celery_app  # noqa
  File "/home/soufiaane/django_projects/CapValue/CapValue/celery_settings.py", line 9, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named 'mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute
    settings.configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in configure
    raise RuntimeError('Settings already configured.')
RuntimeError: Settings already configured.
```

which clearly indicates that i have an issue regarding mysql database support!

after struggeling with the mysql-connector-python package i was using in my devloppment version, i couldn't get it working on my linux server due to some compatibility issues.

so i end up installing mysqlclient package insteed and it worked like a charm!